# In ASP.MVC, how to place JavaScript-friendly Stack trace of exceptions in ViewData?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

When any exception occurs on the ASP.MVC server side code, I would like to take the entire stack trace of the exception and place in the ViewData and returns to the client.  For example:

```
try
{
    //some code
}
catch (SomeException e)
{        
    ViewData["exceptionStack"] = e.StackTrace;
}
```

The JavaScript on the client side would just take the string in the ViewData and display it.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var exceptionStack = '<%= ViewData["exceptionStack"] %>';
</script>
```

The problem is how I can ensure, either via regex or other means, either on the server side using C# or on the client that the JavaScript variable **exceptionStack** would NOT contain any illegal character, so that when I do:

```
$('#someElement').text(exceptionStack);
```

or

```
$('#someElement').html(exceptionStack);
```

there won't be any error.

Comment: u should use url encode i think.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that using HtmlEncode would work.  So from the controller:

```
// Stuff in the controller action that may cause an error
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ViewData["exceptionStack"] = Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString());
}
```

If for some reason Html Encoding doesn't work for you, or you want to be extra secure, you can also use the [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library:

```
// Stuff in the controller action that may cause an error
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ViewData["exceptionStack"] = AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(ex.ToString());
}
```

The HtmlEncoding is available as an HtmlHelper:

```
<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["exceptionStack"]) %>
```

And you can easily create wrappers for the AntiXSS libraries

```
public static string JavaScriptEncode(this HtmlHelper helper, string input)
{
    return AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(input);
}
```

Which can then be used in the same way:

```
<%= Html.JavaScriptEncode(ViewData["exceptionStack"]) %>
```

Of course AntiXSS also has encoding for Html, XML, VBScript and Url encoding, so you could add a helper for any or all of those.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is HtmlHelper.Encode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var exceptionStack = '<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["exceptionStack"] %>)';
</script>
```

Comment: ckramer's answer much better.